# "Attaching" pivot chart labels to bottom of graph

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a chart that I am using to keep track of weekly data. It is a Pivot table with an attached graph. Every week when I refresh the data the chart moves back to the following picture.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFi6q.png)

With the Data labels shoved inside of the bottom of the chart. I Spend a bit of time every week moving all of them back down. I would like to anchor them with the upper right corner attaching to the bottom axis. The only placement option in the Pivot chart are Center, Inside End, Inside Base, Outside end. I am using inside base to get the picture I mentioned.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqMlT.jpg) is what I change it to each week. As you can see I drag all of them down individually and try to get them to line up as best as I can by hand. But they are never perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found my problem, The issue was I was using Data Labels and not axis labels.

If you are having this problem go Pivotchart tools > Design > Add chart Element > Axes > Primary Horizontal.